# Regex Beginner; Writing Lex/Flex compatible Regular Expressions (specifically to identify even integers)

Tags: regex, compilation, bison, flex-lexer, lex

So I am looking to write a simple flex program, in which I would like to use a Regex Expression to identify integers (and separating them from any "whitespace"). I then use C code blocks, in which I will increment **integerCount** and **evenCount** (initialised to 0) respectively. I am completely new to both Flex and writing regular expressions. I am using the book [Flex/Bison by O'Reilly Media](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596155988.do) as a reference
   for writing flex programs. Because I am unfamiliar with regular expressions in general, I resorted to google for read-ups which has lead me to the following websites:

- [Regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) helped me understand regular expressions better as I
  was able to toy around with them and see in real time the changes I
  am actually making. The problem is that I was able to successfully
  write the regex I wanted on the website (I going to put this down at the *bottom of the page* so it is formatted better) however it does not function as intended
  within flex. This lead me to realise that flex does not use the same
  notation/rules for Regular Expressions that I am used to.
- [This site compares the Rules of regular expressions in Perl, Grep
  and Lex.](http://marvin.cs.uidaho.edu/Handouts/regex.html) As you can see, many of the functionalities I have used
  to build my regular expressions aren't compatible with Lex. As I understand it, I am not working with *whitespace* per say, but ASCII space, carridge return etc.

Below is the Regex Expression I had created on Regexr.com to identify stray even integers.

```
    \d+[02468]+((\n)|(\s)|($)){1}
```

As this is compatible, I had to make some changes. I can figure out how to swap \d with [0-9], however swapping \n with carriage return to \x0D  and \s with space \x0 doesn't seem to be the right approach.

I am using flex to compile the program to lex.yy.c , and calling "cc lex.yy.c -lfl" to compile it to the a.out executable program. This works only on Linux and not OSX.

[Here is a link to my solution.l program at the moment.](https://github.com/avieor/flex/blob/master/solution.l)

If you have any advice for me, I would really appreciate your guidance. In any case, thank you for reading.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Are you simply searching for help about how to match even integers? If so, can you provide more detail about the format? Is each integer on a separate line?

Answer (score 1):

To match integers, you simply need:

```
[[:digit:]]+               { /* handle a number */ }
```

If you want to match even integers, you can use

```
[[:digit:]]*[02468]        { /* handle an even number */ }
```

If you want to match both even and odd integers, doing something different for each parity, you would use two rules:

```
[[:digit:]]*[02468]        { /* handle an even number */ }
[[:digit:]]*[13579]        { /* handle an odd number */ }
```

Or you could do it with the first two patterns, as long as you put them into in the right order:

```
[[:digit:]]*[02468]        { /* handle an even number */ }
[[:digit:]]+               { /* handle any other number */ }
```

This works because (f)lex always uses the first rule if two patterns are equally good.

There's no point in trying to match whitespace or newlines as part of the number. They're not part of the number, and the idea of flex is that you are breaking the input up into meaningful pieces ("tokens"). It might be that you don't care about other pieces of the input, but you still need to recognise them, if only to explicitly ignore them. For example, to ignore anything which is not a digit, you could add the following rule:

```
[^[:digit:]]               ; /* Do nothing*/
```

The semi-colon is required because (f)lex doesn't allow empty actions.

Now, it's possible that your intention was to not count numbers in the middle of a word, like `F29` or `23skidoo`. In that case, you would want to add another pattern which recognises those strings which might contain numbers. Then you will probably have to recognise whitespace explicitly, rather than lumping it in with "not a digit". Surprisingly, this is pretty simple:

```
[[:digit:]]*[02468]        { /* handle an even number */ }
[[:digit:]]+               { /* handle any other number */ }
[[:space:]]+               ; /* Ignore whitespace */
[^[:space:]]+               ; /* Ignore everything else */
```

The last pattern might need some explanation, since a number is also a sequence of non-whitespace characters. But it works for the same reason we don't need an explicit match for odd numbers; the "maximal munch" rule says that (f)lex always uses the pattern with the longest match, and if there is more than one pattern tied for longest match, it uses the first one. In other words, if a sequence of characters delimited by whitespace happens to be a number, one of the number rules will be chosen rather than the last rule. On the other hand, if a number is immediately followed by garbage, the last rule will be used because it has a longer match.

Comment: Note that the last variant will also discard `23+42` as a single non-numeric token. If the goal is to count numbers in a programming language, you'd want to discard `x42`, but not `23+42`. So you'd need a rule that specifically discards identifiers only (and another one that discards non-digit characters). Then you'd probably also want a rule for string literals. But if the input is just a space-separated list of numbers, none of that is necessary of course.

Comment: You can also just check whether a number is even in the action instead of having different regexen for odd and even numbers. I don't know whether that's the intent of the assignment though.

Comment: @sepp2k: I don't know what the assignment is either, of course, but I was trying to show how lexical analysis works. This is undoubtedly an entry-level exercise, without any intention (yet) of handling string literals.

Comment: Rici, I want to just give my appreciation for your post. Sepp2k I am thankful for your comments too. Can I please ask where did you guys get this information regarding Lex's regular expression notation? I haven't spotted them within the textbook I am using (I don't believe so anyway), and I am only finding limited information via google search. I am inclined to believe there exists a better reference that you guys might know of. Thanks again!! :)

Comment: @EoinDowling: It's in the [Flex manual](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns). (And lots of other useful info, too.) Enjoy.